# Problem in getting the accuracy 'train_score' and 'test_score' using Random Forest regressor

Tags: python-3.x, list, dataframe, numpy, random-forest

I tried to run the code below, but I have received the error below. I have a problem to get the 'train_score' and  'test_score'. I would be happy if you can advise me how to fix this error.

```
import numpy as np

from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier

from sklearn.ensemble import forest

import sklearn.ensemble 

mse_train1 = []

mse_test1 = []

num_trees1 = []

train_scores, test_scores = list(), list()

model = RandomForestRegressor (n_estimators = 1 ,min_samples_leaf = 7, n_jobs=-1, oob_score=True,random_state=0)

i = 0

for iter in range(10):

    num_trees1.append(iter)

    i=+1

    model.fit(train_set_RF, train_set_pred)

    y_train_predicted = model.predict(train_set_RF)

    train_score =  model.score(train_set_pred, y_train_predicted)

    train_scores.append(train_score)
    
    y_test_predicted = model.predict(test_set_RF)

    test_score =  model.score(test_set_pred, y_test_predicted)

    test_scores.append(test_score)    

    mse_train = mean_squared_error(train_set_pred, y_train_predicted)

    mse_train1.append(mse_train)

    mse_test = mean_squared_error(test_set_pred, y_test_predicted)

    mse_test1.append(mse_test)

    print("Iteration: {} Train mse: {} Test mse: {}".format(iter, mse_train, mse_test))

    model.n_estimators += 1

print (train_scores)

print (test_scores) 

print (mse_train1)

print (mse_test1)
```

This more detail about the error I got:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call 

last)

<ipython-input-17-ff545aa1896c> in <module>

     19     y_train_predicted = model.predict(train_set_RF)

     20     #y_train_predicted = 

np.nan_to_num(y_train_predicted.astype(np.float32))

---> 21     train_score =  model.score(train_set_pred, y_train_predicted)

     22 

     23     #train_acc = accuracy_score(train_set_pred, 

y_train_predicted)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in score(self, X, y, 

sample_weight)

    549 

    550         from .metrics import r2_score

--> 551         y_pred = self.predict(X)

    552         return r2_score(y, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)

    553 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in 

predict(self, X)

    781         check_is_fitted(self)

    782         # Check data

--> 783         X = self._validate_X_predict(X)

    784 

    785         # Assign chunk of trees to jobs

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\ensemble\_forest.py in 

_validate_X_predict(self, X)

    419         check_is_fitted(self)

    420 

--> 421         return self.estimators_[0]._validate_X_predict(X, 

check_input=True)

    422 

    423     @property

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\_classes.py in 

_validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)

    386         """Validate X whenever one tries to predict, apply,

 predict_proba"""

    387         if check_input:

--> 388             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")

    389             if issparse(X) and (X.indices.dtype != np.intc or

    390                                 X.indptr.dtype != np.intc):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in 

inner_f(*args, **kwargs)

     71                           FutureWarning)

     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, 

args)})

---> 73         return f(**kwargs)

     74     return inner_f

     75 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in 

check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype, order, copy, 

force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd, ensure_min_samples, 

ensure_min_features, estimator)

    622                     "Reshape your data either using 

array.reshape(-1, 1) if "

    623                     "your data has a single feature or 

array.reshape(1, -1) "

--> 624                     "if it contains a single sample.".format(array))

    625 

    626         # in the future np.flexible dtypes will be handled like 

object dtypes

ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:

array=[0.3119313  0.29728386 0.29309732 ... 0.30558413 0.29317933 

0.29755104].

Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a 

single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Comment: I searched about this error and I tried to change some staff in my code, but I am still have the error. I would like to know what is the problem in my code.

Comment: That what I am tried to do train_set_RF= train_set_RF.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_train_predicted= y_train_predicted.reshape(-1, 1)
    y_train_predicted = model.predict(train_set_RF) , but this doesn't work as well.

Comment: Can you share the full error in the question, i.e., starting from the word "Traceback"?

Comment: ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-ff545aa1896c> in <module>
     19     y_train_predicted = model.predict(train_set_RF)
     20     #y_train_predicted = np.nan_to_num(y_train_predicted.astype(np.float32))
---> 21     train_score =  model.score(train_set_pred, y_train_predicted)

Comment: ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[0.3119313  0.29728386 0.29309732 ... 0.30558413 0.29317933 0.29755104].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.

Comment: Hard to read in the comments; can you please edit the question and add it there?

Comment: This is the error I got

Comment: ok, I will do that

Comment: I sent you all the error I got

Comment: Did you look at what `score` function is supposed to do? What arguments should it take?

Comment: Yes, It takes two arguments  and that what I did

Comment: Sure but first argument you're passing is some prediction array `y`, but it needs some `X` i.e., features matrix.

Comment: It watkes to arguments: predict values and acutual values and that what I did

Comment: No that's not what it takes. That's what `mean_squared_error` takes, for example. But not `score`. Documentation is here: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.score

Comment: for solution please try `train_score = model.score(train_set_RF, train_set_pred)` and similar for `test_score`. First argument is samples you pass so that it calculates predictions for it; and it compares it with the second argument which is supposed to be the actual values. This returns R2 coefficient, as written in the link above.

Comment: I tried that and this what I got [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]
[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0] for train_score and test_score

Comment: Yes so problem is solved? or are you asking what do those numbers mean?

Comment: Those are R2 coefficients as I mentioned above.

Comment: Yes, it solved. Thank you so much much appreciated